# Merge two PDF files containing even and odd pages of a book

Tags: pdf, pdftk

I have two searchable PDF  documents, say `even.pdf` and `odd.pdf` which contain even and odd pages of a book, respectively.

I can decompile each PDF to separate files `001.pdf` `002.pdf` `003.pdf`, et cetera. The question is how to merge them?

They are both even and odd sequences numbered `1, 2, 3`. If the numbering in the decompile process with `pdftk` were different, e.g. `1, 3, 5` for even and `2, 4, 6` for odd instead of `1, 2, 3, 4`, I could simply merge them.

Can I do this any other way?

Comment: Same question on
[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12200450/5267751)
[Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/53295/296692)

Answer (score 59):

A simple solution would be to use only [pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) in the following way:

```
pdftk A=odd.pdf B=even.pdf shuffle A Bend-1 output merged.pdf
```

This also works if odd pages are scanned first and then even:

```
pdftk A=file.pdf  shuffle A1-X Bend-Y output new-file.pdf
```

where X is the last odd page and Y is X+1.

Comment: Awesome! It even reverses the order of the odd pages, such that I can simply run the document through my scanner twice (once on each side), instead of manually reshuffling the pages before scanning again.

Comment: How can I use this with the `*` parameter. It does not work because it is going through the files like 1,10,100,101,...,2,20,21...

Comment: Should be `A=odd.pdf B=even.pdf` IMHO. (Note that 1 is an odd number.)

Comment: Second example above (odd/even -> combined) is incorrect because there is no B document; please correct. What worked (30 pages, odds scanned first then evens, evens are reverse order because you don't want to rearrange the stack of paper): `pdftk odd-even.pdf shuffle 16-end 15-1 output combined.pdf`. In the GUI this can be done with Advanced Output Options `%PDFTK% %PDFIN% shuffle 16-end 15-1 output %PDFOUT%`.

Comment: @CaptainNormal, your corrected example seems to have odd and even pages reversed? I would expect it to be `shuffle 1-15 end-16` instead (which is also what worked in my own test). In any case, I've proposed an edit to the original answer based on your suggestion of omitting the A/B labels entirely, and added an example for a 30-page document as well (it's still in the moderation queue atm).

Comment: @MatthijsKooijman You are 100% correct. I don't know how that mistake made it in. Correct is, as you say, for example `pdftk odd-even.pdf shuffle 1-6 end-7 output combined.pdf` for a 12-page document.

Answer (score 33):

From the PDFtk homepage:

> PDFtk has a special feature that we added specifically to solve this problem
>   of arranging scanned pages: shuffle. Say you have two PDFs: even.pdf and
>   odd.pdf. Then you can collate them into a single document like this:
>
> ```
> pdftk A=odd.pdf B=even.pdf shuffle A B output collated_pages.pdf
> ```
>
> If your even pages are in reverse order, you can reverse its page range:
>
> ```
> pdftk A=odd.pdf B=even.pdf shuffle A Bend-1 output collated_pages.pdf
> ```
>
> The shuffle feature works by taking one page at a time from each of the input
>   page ranges and assembling them into a new PDF. You specify these ranges after the 
>   shuffle keyword, and you can have more than two ranges.

An example of the use of more ranges is:

```
pdftk A=odd.pdf B=even.pdf shuffle A1 B1 A5-6 B2-3 output out.pdf
```

in which case the output contains the first page of A (A1), the first page of B (B1), then the fifth page of A, the second of B, the sixth page of A and finally the third page of B.

Comment: FYI: I *think* `Bend-1` means `B` document, from `end` to page `1`. Since the end comes after 1, they are in reverse order. If they were 10 pages, alternatively, you could say `B10-1`. I thought it meant 'bend the pages'.

Comment: +1 to @Chloe for the explanation! I was wondering what the heck bend meant. This is a great overall example and alternate use cases, so +1 to Melgaard too! Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 7):

Check out Sejda - A New Advanced Online PDF Manipulation Tool

http://sejda.com/

It has the ability to merge docs in different ways, and may be able to accomplish your requirements above - the [Alternate and Mix task](https://www.sejda.com/alternate-mix-pdf) appears to do what you're asking for.

[image: Alternate and Mix PDF files using Sejda.com]

Comment: Yeah if you want to pay 6 bucks a month.

Comment: It actually has a pretty generous free tier for occasional users

Answer (score 4):

Of the top of my head, I would combine `pdftk` with `mmv`:

- First burst both files into separate directories, getting `even/001.pdf` and `odd/001.pdf` etc.
- Then use `mmv '*.pdf' '#1-a.pdf'` on the odd folder, `mmv '*.pdf' '#1-b.pdf'` on the even folder.
- Move everything into one folder. The shell expansion `*` should now sort odd pages before even pages (001-a, 001-b, 002-a, 002-b etc.).
- Use pdftk as in `pdftk *.pdf cat output combined.pdf`

Maybe you have to do the last bit in loops for, say, the first thirty pages, then another thirty pages etc., depending on how robust your shell expansion is with many files.

Answer (score 4):

I use the free and open source PDF Split and Merge module called [PDF SAM Alternate Mix](http://www.pdfsam.org/mix-pdf/).
[Github link](https://github.com/torakiki/pdfsam)

Besides being able to merge files it is capable of other interesting operations.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem. One file containing the odd, one file containing the even pages of a scanned book. I simply used the built in Windows 7/8/8.1 batch rename capability.

1) Split the pages of each pdf back into seperate files for each page such that one folder contains all odd pages as seperated files and a different folder contains all even pages.

2) Bulk/Batch/Mass rename the files of both folders in the same way. Simply select all files in each folder and rename the first one as *a* and hit enter. In doing so, the files in each of the two folders will be numbered as *a(1),a(2),a(3)...*

3) In the folder with the odd pages, copy all files and paste them directly into the same folder. In doing so, it creates copies of the files with the odd pages that will look like *a(1) - Copy*

4) Move these copied files to the folder containing the even files. This sorts them in front of the even page files (as long as the files are sorted by their names).

5) Merge the the files back into one file by simply following the new naming scheme.

In order to merge and split the pdf files I used *pdfIll's Pdf Tools* which is available for free.

Comment: If you are using [PDFill](https://www.pdfill.com/download.html) to split pages in the PDFs to their own files, it asks for a name, so you can skip the mass rename (since they already have the correct names).  Be sure to check that 10 is after 9 (and not between 1 and 2).  Drag and drop works, the `Add PDF Files under a Folder` button does not.

Answer (score 0):

[PDFSam Basic](https://pdfsam.org/download-pdfsam-basic/) is free and the merging process is much faster than what I am accustomed to on Adobe Acrobat. (It took about 3 seconds to merge two 200-page, 50MB files, interleaved. Whereas it would've taken at least 10 seconds on Adobe Acrobat, without the interleaving feature.)

The only possible drawback is that you have to install it on your system.
[Github link](https://github.com/torakiki/pdfsam)

Answer (score 0):

If you are scanning documents fronts first and backs second, the GNOME "Document Scanner" app (Simple Scan) can combine the scans via the "Reorder Pages" tool. "Combine Sides" is the option you're looking for:

[image: Simple Scan Reorder Pages Tool]

Answer (score 0):

Using `qpdf`:

```
qpdf --empty --collate=1 --pages A.pdf B.pdf -- out.pdf
```

Answer (score -1):

well what you are asking is slightly complicated, but for starters you could try something like [Combine PDFs Free](http://combinepdf.cc/) or any other page. If you have trouble let me know and i can try help :P

regards
cam

Answer (score -1):

I think he is opting for a little bit more flexibility in functionality.
That makes your combinepdf option totally useless. Better give [Online PDF](http://online-pdf.org)
a try. That will put you in command at least...

Comment: First of all, please don’t use an answer to comment on another answer. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post – you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). ... (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) ... (2) How does “Online PDF” answer this question? I took a quick look at it – I uploaded two PDF files – and I didn’t see an option for interleaving their pages. (3) And even if “Online PDF” can do what the question asks for, is there anything that makes it preferable to `pdftk` (which has been mentioned in two answers)?