# How do I merge two PDF files and insert the same single page into another 744 times?

Tags: pdf, pdftk

I saw this answer: https://superuser.com/a/598688/130929

But it was for files with the same number of pages. I have a PDF with 744 addresses and I have a single page letter for the contents which is the same. I would like to merge them to get a 1488 page PDF file so I can print it double-sided and the address will be on one side and the letter will be on the other side. How can I do this with `pdftk`?

The help says it will stop using a document if the pages runs out.

```
      shuffle [<page ranges>]
             Collates pages from input PDFs to create a new PDF.  Works
             like the cat operation except that it takes one page at a
             time from each page range to assemble the output PDF.  If one
             range runs out of pages, it continues with the remaining
             ranges.  Ranges can use all of the features described above
             for cat, like reverse page ranges, multiple ranges from a
             single PDF, and page rotation.  This feature was designed to
             help collate PDF pages after scanning paper documents.
```

I think

```
pdftk A=addresses.pdf B=letter.pdf shuffle A B B B B B B B B B B B...x744 output collated.pdf
```

Might work, but that seems unwieldy. Maybe if I could duplicate the letter page 744 times, then `shuffle collate` them, that might also work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it by opening the single-page PDF in PDF Viewer Plus, selecting all pages with CTRL-A, holding down CTRL, and dragging to insert and copy the pages, and repeating this about 9 times, thanks to exponential growth. Then I selected 82 more pages and copied them the same way to arrive at 594 pages. I had started the hard way by printing and re-feeding the paper and managed to get 150 copies done already (744-150=594). Once I had a PDF of the inside, I used `pdftk` to collate them into one PDF available for double-sided printing. I started on page 151 because I had already printed 150 the hard way. This was the command I used to collate them.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk\bin\Pdftk.exe" A="Addresses - Chloe.pdf" B="Flyer - Google Docs-x594.pdf" shuffle A151-end B output flyer.pdf
```